# Erro 500 quando tento dar um post de um JSON para o web service C#

Tags: c#, json, winforms

Eu tenho uma aplicação WINDOWS FORM C#, onde me comunico com um web service, quando tento enviar um dado muito grande da minha aplicação para o web service recebo o erro 500.

Consigo fazer um POST em qualquer outro objeto em JSON, mas quando é este que contém dados muito grandes ele dá pau,  o fato interessante é que se eu tentar dar um get, consigo recuperar esses dados para minha aplicação, só não consigo enviar para o server.

Os dados grandes são: uma foto convertida para base64 e um arquivo em binário que também é convertido para base64.

Segue o código que faço o post:

```
public void POST(string url, string jsonContent)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";

        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(jsonContent);

        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ContentType = @"application/json";
        

        using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
        long length = 0;
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                length = response.ContentLength;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
        
            // Log exception and throw as for GET example above
        }
    }
```

Esse método funciona legal com json's menores.

Quem aí tem uma noção de como posso resolver esse meu problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A primeira coisa que eu faria seria essa configuação no WS:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxMessageLength="409600"
    executionTimeoutInSeconds="300"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Se ainda assim a não resolver existem outras opções. [Aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx) você pode ver melhor todas as opções que o framework lhe lá.

Comment: Se eu utilizar o finder por exemplo ou o POSTMAN , com o mesmo JSON que eu gero , ele aceita , mas especialmente minha aplicação quando eu tento enviar este objeto eu recebo exceção ,